# Subscribe to newsletter at payment page

Tags: magento2, newsletter, third-party-module

I tried this module: https://mageside.com/subscribe-at-checkout-2.html to subscribe customers to newsletters during checkout,
but it adds the checkbox into shipping step and I want it in payment step, after payment methods.

I have tried to change layout in SubscribeLayoutProcessor.php, as: `'billing-step' => 'children' => 'payment' => 'children' => 'afterMethods' => 'children' => 'newsletter-subscribe'`.

It shows up correctly but check and uncheck functionality does not work, it seems that the module observes for `ms_subscribeatcheckout_place_order_after` event and moving it into payment step seems difficult?

Can someone help with ideas on how to do it, or is it better to create a custom one?